# Retrieve blob from sqlite

Tags: android, sqlite, blob, android-sqlite

I would like to retrieve a blob from my database base on the row position

I'm retrieving the data from the SQLite database using a cursor

```
 public Cursor getTestData(int index,String house) 
 { 
     try 
     { 
         String sql ="SELECT * FROM Heroes where position ="+ index +" and house='"+house+"'";             
         Cursor mCur = mDb.rawQuery(sql, null); 
         if (mCur!=null) 
         { 
            mCur.moveToFirst(); 
         } 
         return mCur; 
     } 
     catch (SQLException mSQLException)  
     { 
         Log.e(TAG, "getTestData >>"+ mSQLException.toString()); 
         throw mSQLException; 
     } 
 }
```

this returns me all the columns and i can get the strings easily by

```
Cursor testdata = mDbHelper.getTestData(pos,house); 
String sName = Utility.GetColumnValue(testdata, "name");
String sAdvance = Utility.GetColumnValue(testdata, "class");
```

this will return my Column "name" and "class" value, but how to retrieve a blob and show it.

```
Byte[] img = Utility.GetImage(testdata, "image1");
```

this is how im trying

```
public static byte[] GetImage(Cursor cur,String ColumnName){
    return cur.getBlob(cur.getColumnIndex(ColumnName));
}
```

but getting null in img :(

Comment: Have you checked that the blob is not actually `NULL`?

Comment: i have added and image using SQLite Manager ! so im pretty sure that it is not null